# Find text string or part of text with dot in grepWin

Tags: regex, string, text, grep

I am using grepWin on Windows 7 64. http://tools.tortoisesvn.net/grepWin.html

I have a folder with files and their duplicate copies.

The original files are named "FILENAME DOT FILETYPE" (without spaces), for example "cartonbox.shelf".

The copies of these file are named "FILENAME DOT 1 DOT FILETYPE" (without spaces),  for example "cartonbox.1.shelf".

I am trying to find all files that contain the exact string:

"DOT 1 DOT FILETYPE" (without spaces), so all files that have for example ".1.shelf" in them.

How can I do that in grepWin please?

If I try "`\.1\shelf`" or "`\.1\.shelf`" for example I do not get any results.

What is my mistake please? Been reading http://www.regular-expressions.info/ but cannot come up with correct pattern.

How can I generally search for an exact part of the filename regardless of symbols?

Basically if the file I want to find has for example "garden_1.1.4-JE50.tree" in it how do I tell grepWin to find this exact string of text including underscore, dots or other characters?

Comment: And what about `.*\.1\.shelf`?

Comment: Same again, no matches.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Grep stands for g/re/p (global / regular expression / print)

It searches IN files, not file names. That text would need to be text-readable in the file for which you are searching.

In the directory you want to search, you could do something like:

```
dir *.* /b/s > my_file.txt
```

Then you can perform your regular expressions checks with grepWin on my_file.txt

In Unix and Linux you normally pipe the commands via the command line:

```
ls -a | grep \.1\.shelf$
```

In Windows you would use

```
dir * /b | findstr \.1\.shelf$
```

**Update 2023**

You can now install the [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install) as well as [GNU Grep.](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/grep.html)

```
dir * /b | grep \.1\.shelf$
```

Or in `WSL` you would use `find` in the directory you're searching:

```
find . -iregex "\.1\.shelf$"
```

Comment: Tried that as well but get no matches unfortunately.

Comment: Also added the dollar sign at the end of the pattern and it does not come up with any matches. For Search I have ticked Regex Search, under Limit search I have All sizes and Regex match ticked, though in the form field above it is empty. Those should be the correct settings, no?

Comment: Oh gosh, so this means also the Text Search option of grepWin will not find the files?

What app/tool/software can do this then?

Comment: You don't need `find` to search the current directory. Simply `ls *.1.shelf` or perhaps [better](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) `for file in ./*.1.shelf; do : something with each "$file"; done`